# Amazon MWS: Shall FeedSubmissionId be a primary key in my database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

SubmitFeed() has been returning "already-existing" IDs for new feeds:

exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '50320017869' for key 'PRIMARY''

The above was recorded at 2018-12-04 22:17:24, i.e. in the evening.

Looking up 50320017869 in the database I can see that:
SubmittedDate: 2018-12-04 09:29:02, i.e. in the morning
StartedProcessingDate: 2018-12-04 09:29:30
CompletedProcessingDate: 2018-12-04 09:30:23
Status: *DONE*
MessagesProcessed: 1
MessagesSuccessful: 1
FeedType: _POST_INVENTORY_AVAILABILITY_DATA_

Today, one day later, I am querying the ID using getFeedSubmissionList() and indeed I am getting the same output above (SubmittedDate: 2018-12-04 09:29:02 ...).

This is all quite disturbing... Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the FeedSubmissionID is supposed to be unique, but I've also seen weird patterns in IDs returned from MWS which combined with relative small numbers (11 digits are not that much if half of them seem constant) makes me wonder if they actually *are*.

The fact that repeated calls to getFeedSubmissionList() keep returning the older feed's data (rather than overwriting that data and giving back results from the newer submission) suggests that those IDs *should* be unique and not be reused.

As a result, I assume you getting the same ID back is a glitch, but I've never stored IDs for long enough to actually run into a key collision myself and cannot tell you how common those are.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have a slew of occurrences with just a handful of accounts and have found posts from 2014 describing the same issue. Right now I am simply disregarding them and retrying SubmitFeed() till I get a brand-new ID. I had no chance to check if the submitted feeds (e.g. inventory) are being processed or not. I am wondering what the (negative) consequences of "multiple submissions" of the same feed could be, particularly with respect to Orders feeds (cancellations, acknowledgements, etc) which I haven't gotten around yet. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @sexybit I'm not sure, but I doubt it'll be much of a problem as you cannot double-acknowledge or double-cancel anything. I can see how it would be difficult to debug. Have you tried to see whether the submitted feed was actually processed using a *different* ID / whether you had submitted feeds with IDs that did not match any in your database?

Comment: Uhm, that's a bit of a relief. Though I assume you can double-adjust something (as in adjustment feed)? It didn't come to mind to check if GetFeedSubmissionList() returns some IDs that I don't have, I will give it a try. Thanks for suggestion! At the very minimum, assuming that the newly-submitted feed is not being processed, this issue *will* result in a delay in the submissions. At times it took a couple of hours (of retries) before I finally got a brand new ID. This past week I registered no new occurrences though. But I don't believe in miracles...